# How do I choose a picture on a background and be able to mark it with a mouse click?

Tags: java, swing, background, image

Im still working on my program and I was wondering if I could choose a background (its a map of europe) and when i click my mouse on it it will mark with little blue circles? Any tips ideas?

Comment: There are already several questions about setting a background image on a JPanel. Just look at the Related section on the right. Do you have a problem with that, or with painting a blue circle? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is to override the paintComponent method.

[Here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/) and [here](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/swing2d/index.html) are good tutorials by oracle on how to do this